# How do I export data into yaml with mapping?

Tags: theming, 8

I am exporting module's libraries from PHP in modulename.libraries.yml. I am using the YAML parser.

```
\Drupal::service('serialization.yaml')->decode($data)
```

The issue I have encountered is that I cannot indicate JavaScript or CSS files to be minified because instead of `filename: { minified: true }` I will end up with the following.

```
filename:
  minified: true
```

Basing on a brief IRC chat, I get this is not possible. Is that correct? If it is so, is this a bug? Differently, can anybody tell me how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two are semantically the same thing. The only difference is that the {} format is more compact.
See the output in these [two](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=filename%3A%0A%20%20minified%3A%20true&type=json) [links](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=filename%3A%20%7B%20minified%3A%20true%20%7D&type=json).

Regardless, the second argument to the dump method lets you configure the verbosity of arrays. See [Writing YAML Files](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/introduction.html#writing-yaml-files).